# Set a module as a dependency to the others in parent config on a maven multimodule project

Tags: java, maven, multi-module

Is there any nice mechanism to declare a module from a multimodule project as a dependency to the rest through the parent aggregator pom? (Perhaps by making common module autoexcluding itself)

Comment: If you choose not to use the parent pom to be inherited in the common module. The parent pom may declare a dependency on the common module and the rest of the  modules which inherit the parent pom will inherit the dependency on the common module as well. But, if you want to have parent pom inheritance in the common module too, then you may choose to have one aggregator pom and one parent pom.

Answer (score 1):

You don't declare the dependency at the parent pom.xml but inside that module's pom.xml. Just declare the dependency as usual:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.mavenbook.multi</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-weather</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

You may want to install each non-dependant module into your local maven repo.

See an example at: https://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html